# Get JavaScript value of JSON from Google Distance Matrix API

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently creating a Distance Info app with the help of Google Maps Distance Matrix Api. Below is my code:

```js
document.getElementById('generateDistance').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var origin = document.getElementById('fromLocation').value;
  var destination = document.getElementById('toLocation').value;

  var distanceUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metrics&origins=" + origin + "&destinations=" + destination + "&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

  window.location = distanceUrl;
});
```

What it does is it opens the url and show the distance information via JSON. What I would want is to get those values and just have it shown on the landing page. Been reading about parsing JSON objects. Can anyone help me understand on having it parsed please?

Comment: you need to use an Ajax get request to get the response .. i have created a fiddle for you to demonstrate ..you have to set your api key there..https://jsfiddle.net/z32u6f2L/

Comment: @talentedandrew But that'll require jQuery, right? I was actually thinking of having it just purely on JavaScript. I've read on the documentation that it can be done by Processing JSON though couldn't understand it so I came here. Here's the link to the reference - [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/web-service-best-practices#ParsingJSON)

Comment: you have to do an ajaxcall so your runtime is able to receive and parse the json data, no problem doing those request with plain js, just search for vanilla ajax or javascript xhr, if you receive the data you can access it just like json#

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting your browser open the url you need an ajax request so your script can handle the response at runtime on your page.

this is just a basic example of how it could work

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', distanceUrl);
xhr.send(null);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
  var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
  if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
    if (xhr.status === OK) {
      plaintext = xhr.responseText;
      responseObject = JSON.parse(plaintext);
      console.log(plaintext); // 'This is the returned text.'
      console.log(responseObject) // Logs the parsed json object you can easily access properties, check the console which they are, assuming there is a property calculatedDistance you could access like:
      console.log(responseObject.calculatedDistance)
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
    }
  }
};
```